# Microsoft Word 2019 get table to push a text box

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-365, microsoft-word-2019

I need a styling pointer for word.

I have the problem in the image attached.
[image: Image showing problem]
What I need to happen is when I insert a new row, the text box should move down. I only need this to start happening when the rows reach the text box. Unfortunately I think the text box is considered part of the table because when I select the table crosshair box in the top left hand side of the table, it also selects that text box. I'm honestly not sure how to proceed.

[Link to Doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1hnZJDeH3KFOwrW-SMgkeZNiFR5duT7VC/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=117854532602291204718&rtpof=true&sd=true)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behaviour of the text box fully depends on the position of the anchor. Right now, your anchor is in row `08.`, so the text box will only move down if that row moves down. Since you are inserting a new row below the row `08.` text box won't move.

If you drag and drop the blue anchor into the row of `Amount Due`, then the text box will move down if you insert a new row right after `08.`

**EDIT** (after receiving the document):

I just saw that you created your document completely out of text boxes. In such a case, I recommend you to recreate your document properly without the use of text boxes. Otherwise, the anchor will always default to the first paragraph at the very top left of your document as soon as you drag it out of the table. Another alternative is, that you can create an additional cell to the left of the "Amount" row and make its borders invisible. Then you could anchor the text box to this cell. But you should really think about properly recreating the document.

Comment: When moving the position of the anchor, the text box moves to right, underneath Amount Due. I need it to retain it's position on the left. If you would like the document I could upload it for you to see?

Comment: Sure, you can upload the file and share a link. Note, that if you select the text wrapping option "In Front of Text", you should be able to move the text box after changing the anchor location

Comment: uploaded the doc. Link is in my edited post.

Comment: @Chamkey that give a good insight on the problem. Please see my edited answer

Comment: Thanks but I'm not really sure how to position all the elements that I need without text boxes. I'll try your second suggestion for now and study up on how to do positioning without text boxes at a later date.

Comment: @Chamkey For the proper formatting, you will mainly need to learn about tabs and paragraph spacing. If you want to continue with the additional cell to the left, the easiest method is, that you split the current "Amount Due" cell into 2 cells. Then double click into the left-most cell and now drag its left border to the left border of the table. Afterwards, drag the right border to the right border to the left border of the "Tax" cell.

Comment: I ended up just using your suggestion to redo the whole thing. I made the document using just tables so that everything could line up without the need for tabs and tab formatting. I drew in all the spacing that I needed whenever I needed it.